# Growth rate of longest sequence of strings where no string is a subsequence of a later one

Tags: asymptotics, order-theory, trees

We define $STR(n)$ to be the longest sequence of strings with $n$ symbols such that the $k$th string has at most k symbols, the symbols of the string are taken from an alphabet consisting of $n$ characters, and no string is a subsequence of a later one.

For example, $STR(1)=2$, because the longest sequence is "A", "". $STR(2)=4$, because the longest sequence is "A", "BB", "B", "". I'm not sure how big $STR(3)$ is (although it is at least 11 due to the sequence "A","BB","BC","CB","B","CCCCC","CCCC","CCC","CC","C","").

We do know, however, that $STR(n)$ is always finite, for the same reason that [$TREE(n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_tree_theorem#TREE.283.29) and [$SSCG(n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedman%27s_SSCG_function) (see [well-quasi-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-quasi-ordering)).

My question, what is the growth rate of $STR(n)$? It is slower than $TREE(n)+1$, since strings can embed in trees.

(In particular, if we could find $n$ such that $STR(n)>TREE(3)$, that would be great.)

Comment: Erm... Apparently you use the word "substring" in an unconventional way (i.e., A is a substring of B if you can get A by deleting some symbols in B). Otherwise I do not really see how STR embeds in TREE

Comment: @fedja map the string "fedja" to the tree (f)-(e)-(d)-(j)-(a) for example (with (f) as root).

Comment: I understand that. What I'm trying to say is that with this embedding, the partial order in TREE does not correspond to the normal person's notion of "substring" (i.e., of being a *consecutive* subsequence)

Comment: @fedja whoops, got substring and subsequence confused. Question edited.

Comment: $STR$ is _extremely_ slower than $TREE$. If we want to speak about ordinals, then $STR$ can be bounded by $f_{\omega^\omega+1}$ in the fast-growing hierarchy (see [here](https://u.osu.edu/friedman.8/files/2014/01/LongFinSeq98-2f0wmq3.pdf), theorem 5.19), while $TREE$ goes way beyond that (way beyond $\Gamma_0$, as Wikipedia mentions), I don't think anyone has proven how far exactly it lies.

Comment: STR(3) is at least 28.  (I should be able to be more definitive in the near future.)  Example achieving this: a,bc,ccc,ccbb,ccb,cc,cbbbbbb,cbbbbb,cbbbb,cbbb,cbb,cb,c,bbbbbbbbbbbbbb,bbbbbbbbbbbbb,bbbbbbbbbbbb,bbbbbbbbbbb,bbbbbbbbbb,bbbbbbbbb,bbbbbbbb,bbbbbbb,bbbbbb,bbbbb,bbbb,bbb,bb,b,empty.

Comment: STR(3) is equal to 28.  I did a depth-first search of the computation tree.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose it's a good idea to turn my comment into an answer.

The function $STR$ is basically the function $F$ defined by Friedman in [this paper](https://u.osu.edu/friedman.8/files/2014/01/LongFinSeq98-2f0wmq3.pdf) (more precisely, it's easy to show $STR(k)=F(k-1)+1$). Friedman pinpoints the growth rate of this function quite precisely in theorem 5.19 of that paper. He uses the following variant of fast-growing hierarchy: $$H_1(x)=2x+1$$ $$H_{\beta+1}(x)=H_\beta^{x+1}(x)$$ $$H_\lambda(x)=H_{\lambda(x)}(x)$$
(where $\lambda(x)$ denotes the $x$-th element of a standard fundamental sequence of $\lambda$ when $\lambda<\varepsilon_0$).

**Theorem:** The function $F$ eventually dominates all functions $H_\beta$ for $\beta<\omega^\omega$ and is itself eventually dominated by $H_{\omega^\omega+1}$.

Hence, in a very precise sense, $F$ has growth rate of approximately $H_{\omega^\omega}$.

On the other hand the function $TREE$ is growing very much faster. An often-quoted lower bound is $f_{\Gamma_0}$ in the fast-growing hierarchy, but I don't think an exact bound like above has been proven.

This way or another, regarding your last question - I haven't bothered to check the details, but I imagine that even with $TREE(3)$ we can construct sequences of trees of length exceeding things like $STR^{STR(5)}(5)$, so we are not going to easily find $n$ such that $STR(n)>TREE(3)$.